# Bootstrap popup does not wait for user's answer

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I have the following javascript function that is called when clicking a Save button. Here is some of the code:

```
   function SaveChanges() {
    if (PreSaveValidation()) {
        // Confirm with user for special case for option C
        if ($(".editable-unsaved[data-value='C']").length > 0) {
            $("#confirmExplicitlyDefinedPercentages").modal("show");
        } else {
            saveNextMonth = false;
        }
        // Save modified rows in selected month
        var rowsToSave = [];
        var rowTypes = [];
```

The problem is that the call to modal("show") on the bootstrap div does not display the popup. The popup is supposed to wait for the user to set the value for the variable saveNextMonth. The rest of the code uses this variable to save the data (not shown).

The popup seems to appear (I think it's a z-index problem because I see it flicker by quickly appearing and disappearing). And the rest of the code gets executed immediately without waiting for the popup answer, which is not what I want.

At first I thought it was the html and how I defined the div but when I make a lonely call to the modal("show"), it pops up so it's not that.

Can someone explain why the popup does not appear and why the code does not wait?

Comment: Can you provide some more context around what triggers this code?

Answer (score 0):

The twitter bootstrap modal popup does not wait for the user on the line where you call the modal() method. The popup appears and disappears and execution continues when you write the code in the way it is shown above.

What I did was remove the modal() call from the SaveChanges() function and placed it in its own function, and then have one of the buttons from the modal popup call the SaveChanges() function.